# Not able to run scm_prepare_database.sh script

Tags: postgresql, cloudera-cdh, cloudera-manager

I am installing Cloudera Manager and CDH 6.3.x and I'm using PostgreSQL for the Cloudera Manager Server and other services that use databases. I'm using a RHEL 7.4 Azure VM and following the official documentation- https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/6/6.3/topics/prepare_cm_database.html

I have completed step 4(Install Databases). In Step 5 : Set up the Cloudera Manager Database, on executing the scm_prepare_database.sh script I'm getting the following error-

```
[root@machine1 ~]# sudo /opt/cloudera/cm/schema/scm_prepare_database.sh postgresql scm scm
Enter SCM password:
JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_181-cloudera
Verifying that we can write to /etc/cloudera-scm-server
Creating SCM configuration file in /etc/cloudera-scm-server
Executing:  /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_181-cloudera/bin/java -cp /usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java.jar:/usr/share/java/oracle-connector-java.jar:/usr/share/java/postgresql-connector-java.jar:/opt/cloudera/cm/schema/../lib/* com.cloudera.enterprise.dbutil.DbCommandExecutor /etc/cloudera-scm-server/db.properties com.cloudera.cmf.db.
Jul 17, 2020 1:59:50 PM org.postgresql.Driver connect
SEVERE: Connection error:
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: Ident authentication failed for user "scm"
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:438)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:222)
        at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:194)
        at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:450)
        at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:252)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
        at com.cloudera.enterprise.dbutil.DbCommandExecutor.testDbConnection(DbCommandExecutor.java:263)
        at com.cloudera.enterprise.dbutil.DbCommandExecutor.main(DbCommandExecutor.java:139)

[                          main] DbCommandExecutor              INFO  Unable to login using supplied username/password.
[                          main] DbCommandExecutor              ERROR Error when connecting to database.
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: Ident authentication failed for user "scm"
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:438)[postgresql-42.1.4.jre7.89c9f79016bab67349a92c00c55907dd.jar:42.1.4.jre7]
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:222)[postgresql-42.1.4.jre7.89c9f79016bab67349a92c00c55907dd.jar:42.1.4.jre7]
        at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)[postgresql-42.1.4.jre7.89c9f79016bab67349a92c00c55907dd.jar:42.1.4.jre7]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:194)[postgresql-42.1.4.jre7.89c9f79016bab67349a92c00c55907dd.jar:42.1.4.jre7]
        at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:450)[postgresql-42.1.4.jre7.89c9f79016bab67349a92c00c55907dd.jar:42.1.4.jre7]
        at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:252)[postgresql-42.1.4.jre7.89c9f79016bab67349a92c00c55907dd.jar:42.1.4.jre7]
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)[:1.8.0_181]
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)[:1.8.0_181]
        at com.cloudera.enterprise.dbutil.DbCommandExecutor.testDbConnection(DbCommandExecutor.java:263)[db-common-6.3.1.96818eaab0a222aa84a7854b8d22c0c7.jar:]
        at com.cloudera.enterprise.dbutil.DbCommandExecutor.main(DbCommandExecutor.java:139)[db-common-6.3.1.96818eaab0a222aa84a7854b8d22c0c7.jar:]
[                          main] DbCommandExecutor              ERROR Exiting with exit code 8
--> Error 8, giving up (use --force if you wish to ignore the error)
```

I had logged into postgres using # sudo -u postgres psql.
PostgreSQL version -  PostgreSQL 9.2.23 on x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-16), 64-bit

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This will solve your problem https://serverfault.com/questions/406606/postgres-error-message-fatal-ident-authentication-failed-for-user

Comment: Thanks. had to install ident server